# How to store very huge set of objects in disk storage rather than in memory (RAM) nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm looking for a solution where we can store huge amount of data (list of objects) in disk rather than in memory (RAM). The reason is because I'm dealing with huge amount of data and some times it is taking so much of memory (RAM) and causing application to crash. When I was facing the same issue in python application I found a solution which is a package called [DiskList](https://pypi.org/project/disklist/) which it helps us to store data in disk rather than in RAM and the performance is also good and the application runs smooth while using that package even we have GB's of data. Is there any package in node.js similar to this or any solution to be considered.

thanks

Comment: About what "data" are you talking ? This in general a application design problem.

Comment: Actually I have to generate a N-ary tree from data in mongodb ( which are nothing but list of objects ) .@Marc

Comment: @p-durga-shankar Work with cursor/pages and split the huge amount of data into smaler chunks and/or "cache" them with the node `fs` module to the HDD/SDD

Comment: @Marc Thanks this is a good solution but can we create Stack like functionality with file either txt or some other format ( POP - delete last/first row in a file , PUSH - append row to the file) as i'm using stack to do the preorder traversal of tree?

Comment: @p-durga-shankar This depends on your implementation, but yes. Perhaps it would be a better soultion to work with streams instead with this overhead ?